# Magento2 Install - Advanced Modules Configurations - where can I know each core modules function?

Tags: magento2, install

While installing **Magento2**, on **Advanced Modules Configurations** page, I find there are 117 core modules already selected

**e.g. Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport**

I believe disable modules I don't use improve performance a little

Where can I know each modules function? so that I can decide to install or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every module (as well as framework component) in Magento 2 has laconic readme file, e.g. [page cache readme](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/PageCache/README.md). Locate necessary readme file using pattern `Magento/<ModuleName>/README.md`